# Angularjs date filter convert time millisecond to UTC not working

Tags: javascript, angularjs, datetime, timezone, angularjs-filter

I am trying to pass timezone to angular js date filter:

```
var _date = $filter('date')(input, 'yyyy/MM/dd HH:mm:ss', 'UTC');
```

where "input" is time in milliseconds. Returned date time string in this case is always in local timezone.

Refer to fiddle example at:
http://jsfiddle.net/Cp73s/6312/

Please let me know what is wrong with this fiddle? Angular version is 1.5.  Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not able to convert using

```
var _date = $filter('date')(input, 'yyyy/MM/dd HH:mm:ss', 'UTC');
```

Edited other way in fiddle,

Added utc conversion functions in filter,

```
myapp.filter('dateFormat', function($filter)
{
 var toUTCDate = function(date){
    var _utc = new Date(date.getUTCFullYear(), date.getUTCMonth(), date.getUTCDate(),  date.getUTCHours(), date.getUTCMinutes(), date.getUTCSeconds());
    return _utc;
  };

 var millisToUTCDate = function(millis){ 
    return toUTCDate(new Date(millis));
  };

 return function(input)
 {
  if(input == null){ return ""; } 
  var _date = $filter('date')(millisToUTCDate(input), "yyyy/MM/dd HH:mm:ss");
  return _date.toUpperCase();
 };
});
```

Check this updated fiddle

http://jsfiddle.net/Cp73s/6312/

Comment: Your solution works. Thanks. Any idea why passing timezone as a argument to date filter does not work (as mentioned in my question)?

Comment: sorry @user613114 I didnt find using filter syntax, I tried with `$filter('date')(input, 'yyyy/MM/dd HH:mm:ss', '+0000');` but didnt get succeed, even I didnt find demo on angular document https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/filter/date